# Xamarin Forms Listview set focus to entry in selected row

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I am using the ListView and in each cell I have a label and an entry to the right side.  When I click on the entry box the keyboard will show up but if I click on the row without clicking on the entry box the keyboard does not.  How can I cause the entry to be focused when its row is selected?

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
 x:Class="Sample7.StartPage">


 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Text="Scanner" Icon="camera.png">
  </ToolbarItem>

  <ToolbarItem Text="Notes" Icon="notes.png" >
  </ToolbarItem>
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


 <ScrollView>
  <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,0">
    <Picker Title="Location" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Items="NuseedDataManager.getWarehouses()"/>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,20,0,20">
     <Label Text="Show All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
     <Switch IsToggled="true"  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="250"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView x:Name="SkuListView" RowHeight="60">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
         <Label Text="TITLE\nawesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1awesome1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="12"/>
         <Entry Text="{Binding CountText}" WidthRequest="70" Keyboard="Numeric" IsFocused="{Binding IsEntryFocused}" />
        </StackLayout>

       </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,20">
     <Button Text="Verify" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>


</ContentPage>
```

```css
namespace Sample7
{
 public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
 {
  ObservableCollection<Cell> skus ;
  public StartPage ()
  {
   InitializeComponent ();

   skus = new ObservableCollection<Cell>();


   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

    if (i < 10) {
     skus.Add(new Cell(){
      BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua,
      CountText = "1"
     });
    } else {

     skus.Add (new Cell () {
      BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
      CountText = "1"
     });

    }
   }

   SkuListView.ItemsSource = skus;

   SkuListView.HeightRequest = SkuListView.RowHeight* skus.Count ()+40;

   SkuListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    Cell c = (Cell)e.SelectedItem;

    c.IsEntryFocused = true;
    c.BackgroundColor = Color.Olive;
    c.CountText = "45";

   };
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new behavior for the entry and set its BindingContext to the ListView instance. If the selected row changes (ItemSelected event), compare the selected item with the item of the current row (entry.BindingContext). In case of a match, focus the entry.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding CountText}" WidthRequest="70" Keyboard="Numeric">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:FocusEntryFromSelectedRowBehavior BindingContext="{x:Reference SkuListView}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>

public class FocusEntryFromSelectedRowBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public Entry AssociatedEntry{ get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
        AssociatedEntry = entry;            
        ((ListView)BindingContext).ItemSelected += MyView_ItemSelected;           
    }

    private void MyView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (AssociatedEntry.BindingContext == e.SelectedItem)
        {
            AssociatedEntry.Focus();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {            
        ((ListView)BindingContext).ItemSelected -= MyView_ItemSelected;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the Focus() method of the Entry.

Comment: where? how? Can you give example please.

Comment: In your ItemSelected method.